# Without calculating the square roots, determine which of the numbers:$a=\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{10}\;\;,\;\; b=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{19}$ is greater.

Tags: proof-verification, arithmetic, radicals

> Without calculating the square roots, determine which of the numbers:
>
> $$a=\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{10}\;\;,\;\; b=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{19}$$
>
> is greater.

My work (I was wondering if there are other ways to prove this):

$$a^2=17+2\sqrt{70}, \;\;b^2=22+2\sqrt{57}$$
$$\sqrt{64}<\sqrt{70}<\sqrt{81}\implies 8<\sqrt{70}<9\implies a^2<35$$
$$\sqrt{49}<\sqrt{57}<\sqrt{64}\implies 7<\sqrt{57}<8\implies b^2>36$$
$$a^2<35<36<b^2\implies a^2<b^2\implies |a|<|b|$$

Comment: Your solution looks fine. I wouldn't waste any more time on it!

Comment: The key phrase is "without calculating the square roots" however, you are still allowed to **approximate** the square root which is not a clear distinction because values of irrational square roots are **always** approximations. There still may be clever ways to get around this.

Comment: The last inequality is $a < b$ because $a,b >0$.

Comment: @Ihf I can write that after, but the square root is an absolute value, so it is the same.

Comment: so multiply them, and check if that's algebraically more than the square of one of them. if not then that one is the larger, if it's equal then they are both the same, and  and if it's larger then the one you squared to compare with is the least.

Comment: @Somos That phrase is wide open to interpretation, in my opinion. e.g., $\sqrt 7 \approx 2.7$, $\sqrt 10 \approx 3.2$, $\sqrt 3 \approx 1.8$, $\sqrt 19 \approx 4.4$. Although these approximations would be considered woefully imprecise for most practical purposes, I believe they would be considered a violation of the rules of the exercise.

Comment: Yeah, there's another way which no one posted @VerkhovtsevaKatya. And that seems to me one of the easiest and less demanding,  though I must admit I didn't read all the answers :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are indeed other ways to do this. Your solution is great, but if you were just curious about another method, here is one:

$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{7} + \sqrt{10} \quad &? \quad \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{19} \\
\sqrt{10} - \sqrt{3} \quad &? \quad \sqrt{19} - \sqrt{7}
\end{align}
$$

Note that instead of comparing $a$ and $b$ directly, we can just compare these values.

Define the function
$$
f(x) = \sqrt{9x+10} - \sqrt{4x+3}
$$
We do this because $f(0) = \sqrt{10} - \sqrt{3}$ and $f(1) = \sqrt{19} - \sqrt{7}$.
The magic step is now figuring out that for all positive $x$, this function is increasing, which tells us that $f(1) > f(0)$.

Of course, seeing that this function is increasing is not exactly obvious, but it is not a difficult task if you have a calculus background.

Perhaps there is another step we can take or a different function we can use that would make the fact it is increasing more obvious?

Answer (score 18):

You can avoid squaring by comparing
$$\eqalign{
\sqrt{12}a&=\sqrt{84}+\sqrt{120}<10+11=21\ ,\cr
\sqrt{12}b&=\sqrt{36}+\sqrt{228}>6+15=21\ .\cr}$$

Comment: Very smart choice of $\sqrt{12}$!

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing it. Using the result that,
$$\sqrt{1+\frac{n}{m}}-\sqrt{1-\frac{n}{m}}  ≥ \frac{n}{m}$$
$$\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{32}}-\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{32}}  >\frac{3}{32}$$
$$\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{32}} > \frac{3}{32}+\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{32}}$$
$$8\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{32}} > \frac{3}{4}+8\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{32}}$$
$$\sqrt{70} > \frac{3}{4}+\sqrt{57}\tag{1}$$

Assuming $a<b$;
$$\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{10}<\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{19}$$
$$17+2\sqrt{70}<22+2\sqrt{57}$$
$$\sqrt{70}<\frac{5}{2}+\sqrt{57}$$
By Using (1);
$$\sqrt{70}<\frac{5}{2}+\sqrt{70}-\frac{3}{4}$$
$$0<1+\frac{3}{4}$$
Hence true, so $a<b$

Answer (score 2):

Since $a$ and $b$ are both positive, it follows that $a<b \iff a^2<b^2$; namely $$a<b\iff17+2\sqrt{70}<22+2\sqrt{57};$$ that is, $a<b$ iff $2\left(\sqrt{70}-\sqrt{57}\right)<5.$ Continuing equivalent statements in this way, we get
$$
a < b
 \iff 508-8\sqrt{3990}<25
 \iff 60 \tfrac38 < \sqrt{3990}
 \iff 3600+45+\tfrac9{64} < 3990,
$$
the latter clearly being the case.

Answer (score 1):

$$a<b\iff a^2<b^2\iff 7+10+2\sqrt {70}<3+19+2\sqrt {57}$$  $$\iff 2\sqrt {70}<5+2\sqrt {57}$$ $$\iff (2\sqrt {70})^2<(5+2\sqrt {57})^2$$ $$\iff 280<25+228+20\sqrt {57}$$ 
 $$\iff 27<20\sqrt {57}$$ and we have $20\sqrt {57}>20\sqrt 4=40>27.$

Another way, from one of the intermediate steps above, is $$a<b\iff 2\sqrt {70}<5+2\sqrt {57}$$ $$\iff 2(\sqrt {70}-\sqrt {57})<5$$ $$\iff 2(\sqrt {70}-\sqrt {57})(\sqrt {70}+\sqrt {57})<5(\sqrt {70}+\sqrt {57})$$ $$\iff 2(70-57)<5(\sqrt {70}+\sqrt {57})$$ and we have $5(\sqrt {70}+\sqrt {57})>5\sqrt {70}>5\sqrt {64}=40>26=2(70-57).$

Or we might notice that $2(\sqrt {70}-\sqrt {57})<2(\sqrt {81}-\sqrt {49})=4<5.$